# Changing Controls' look and feel in WinForms without checking out the form in the source control

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I have a winform with a lot many UI components in it. At the moment, the form is checked-in source control. The controls' look and feel is changed at the runtime and it is done in the **OnLoad** event of the form. The problem that I am encountering at the moment is that when form is getting loaded and controls' look and feel is getting changed, the form.cs is getting checked out automatically in source control. I am eager to know if there is another way of achieving the intended functionality i.e, form must not be checked out if controls' look and feel is changed on runtime.

Comment: @nkoniishvt : why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 0):

its not at runtime this happens but when you open your forms in the "visual ???" designer of visual studio.

before changing any properties in a load or shown event check this first :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
...

if (!DesignMode && !(LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime))
{
    // change runtime properties here
}
```

This ensures that this code is only executed at runtime, not at desingtime when opening forms in the visual designer